# how to save List<List<String>> in android data

Tags: java, android

```
List<List<String>> array;

get(); set();
```

save by button, load at startup

restrictions: android

I tried to use SharedPreferences

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to save List<List<String>> in android data to use it